# Writing a Clang static checker for Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang

Clang support writing of custom checker for it's static analyzer.

Visual Studio supports compiling using clang.

Is it possible to write a Clang custom checker to be used in Visual Studio?

Comment: Looks like someone did this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FredericHeem.CppFixItAddIn but doesn't look like it's maintained anymore